# ODI hangs while loading the temp table to Oracle SQL Developer, tested on QA and DEV. process hangs on the same records. what could be the problem?

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

[1]ODI hangs while loading data to temp table. there is no error from ODI side, its just shows that the job is in progress. i tried clearing some space, restarting the database but it still hangs.

ODI hangs while loading the temp table to Oracle SQL Developer, tested on QA and DEV. process hangs on the same records. what could be the problem?

Comment: Hi, can you check if there are some transactions uncommitted on that table? maybe it's blocked.